# How do I reinstall Vista from CD room on a HP Pavilion DV9000?

Tags: boot, laptop, windows-vista

i already have windows 7 on my laptop , i want to remove it and install windows vista , how can i do that from CD room? , someone kindly tell me the steps.
p.s : i need to do that without formatting hard disk.

Comment: See this page...http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Installing-and-reinstalling-Windows-Vista

Answer (score 1):

1. Purchase retail Vista DVD from a retailer
2. Insert DVD in to DVD ROM drive
3. Reboot laptop if it is powered on
4. Press F2 or Del key to enter BIOS
5. Set DVD ROM as first boot device
6. Save and Exit. Laptop will reboot
7. Press a key when the screen says *Press any key to boot from CD*
8. Follow on screen instructions to install Windows Vista on you Laptop